# Cross area ViewComponents

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a ViewComponent stored in an area named "Dashboard" but now I want to use this ViewComponent in another area called "Appplications".  Yes I could add it to the root views/shared folder but I'm striving to make a very modular application through the strong contained use of areas.

ASP.NET 5 RC1 MVC 6 doesn't seem to support cross area references to other components.

How do I add additional view locations?  I need to add:
`/Areas/Dashboard/Views/Shared/Components/DashboardMenu/Default.cshtml`
as a search location to the view renderer

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/DashboardMenu/Default' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Areas/Applications/Views/Application/Components/DashboardMenu/Default.cshtml
/Areas/Applications/Views/Shared/Components/DashboardMenu/Default.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Components/DashboardMenu/Default.cshtml.
```

Comment: If it is a common component and being used by multiple places in your app, shouldn't you move that to the Shared folder in root ?

Comment: Wouldn't that be "crossing the stream"? I mean... areas were meant to isolate parts of your application. Why are you trying to "deisolate" them?

Comment: Plus... what @Shyju said.

Comment: I have one Area which is dedicated to providing these common basic and consistent dependencies.  Cross area dependencies will be kept to a minimum but the source will always be supplied from this single area.  Additional areas supplied will have no cross dependency apart from this single area.  One area for templating and styling, another area for core stuff then other areas feeding from both these, which could potentially be swapped out to provide the same functionality. Just like swapping out a steering wheel of a car for a pink fur wheel :-)  My other areas will be security, apps, CMS etc.

Comment: It is my goal to stick to the ethos you are both suggesting with the exception of this one maybe two areas that act as a foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out...

Startup.cs

```
// Add additional razor view engine configuration to facilitate:
// 1. Cross area view path searches
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new RazorViewLocationExpander());
});
```

Then create a class called RazorViewLocationExpander.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class RazorViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context) { }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        List<string> locations = viewLocations.ToList();

        locations.Add("/Areas/dashboard/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml");

        return locations;
    }
}
```

I would not recommend this generally.  I am using this solution as a special case because I am using an area to isolate templating and core code for my other (members-only) areas to consume - so they need to know where to find this shared code.  I am attempting to separate the public code from the admin code and this is the cleanest, most modular solution I can think of.  The dashboard area will be present for all website that require members-only administration area.  It is bending the rules of MVC ever so slightly.

Comment: I'll add some word of wisdom... "It's not because you can that you should". It's definitely hacky as hell, it's not discoverable and getting on this project would make me insta-cringe.

Comment: I welcome your comments because I think there are different approaches to modularity with MVC.  The main content of the site should be kept to public content area only, so one of my goals is for clarity.  The root IMO should be for public only.  I am trying to avoid pollution of two sets of source code here.  That leaves me two choices - use areas or create a separate website.  Since I have chosen a single website (for efficiency, maintenance, costs reasons), I am herded towards Areas.  For the views in areas to be shared with other areas this is an action I must take.  Hacky - only slightly.

Comment: I am also very mindful of the complications / headaches this could cause and I am doing so cautiously.  E.g. looking in two areas for Index where the controller has the same name might be ....an issue.

Comment: Maybe instead of going through the areas section (especially if it's only for views) you could create a whole different location. This would prevent confusion between areas and actual root views. No?

Comment: Depends what you mean by whole different location?  The conventions of MVC must still be followed which means where would be public stuff along side administration stuff.  I am attempting to use an area for a different location and thus provide the isolation I am seeking.  Just needs a little tweak here, and a little tweak there... :-)

Comment: I am writing code now to discover the areas on a project and add the shared view folder for each area. Areas have an attribute on the controllers now so hopefully it won't need to be discoverable - just plonk in a class and ensure the configuration line is in Startup.cs.  I will post back here if it doesn't work out well...

Comment: Well... you are already throwing the convention away by introducing cross areas dependencies. If you are introducing your own... don't meld them with the old one. Start something new. Maybe an `AreaBaseView` folder? Not sure exactly on what is the best but it's better than putting it in the `Areas` folder. If your area isn't an actual area... it shouldn't go in `Areas`. It add confusion with the original conventions.